# Is there any way to have a discord bot in JavaScript and some comands in python?

Tags: javascript, python, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I have a discord bot in discord.js, but I have found a free version of the cleverbot API https://github.com/plasticuproject/cleverbotfree and I want to have a command that works with that API. Is there a way to execute python in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most likely no direct way that isn't super janky. You might want to set up a python program that exposes the information you need via an API and use that information in your node program.